# iPad 2 shows blank black screen after launch randomly on device

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller, ipad-2, ios-universal-app

I'm newer to xcode and have picked up this universal app project from another dev who never could figure out how to fix a bug that was in the code because he said that he could not replicate it.

I have 4 different testing devices and I'm able to get the app to work fine on 3 of the 4. iPad retina, iPhone 4, and iPhone 3 all work. It also works fine in simulator. It's the iPad 2 that has been getting the error.

There is a blank / black screen that appears after the application loads. The default.png file shows during loading and then after that the screen goes blank. There is a looping music file that plays on the main view controller iPad_HomeViewController.m. I can hear this playing so I know the app is running, but the screen is blank and you can't use the app. Sometimes the app loads up perfectly and works correctly and then after a few uses of closing it out and reopening it the blank screen appears again. I've also seen it load the iPad_HomeViewController for just a few seconds so that you can see all the graphics and the navigation buttons and then it goes blank/black. I can usually get the blank screen to go away by closing the app out completely and relaunching or by powering the device off completely and then turning it back on and relaunching.

I'm working with xcode 4.3.3

Comment: Try upgrading XCode (Mac App Store), and checking the code for any UI editing, etc.

Comment: so you really think that it is just this version of xcode that is causing it? Also it's not just a testing device only situation. We have many of these apps that are live and people are reporting the random black / blank screen as well on iPad 2.

Comment: Well, if the same XCode was used to compile it (you only send compiled apps, as far as I know, to Apple), then that just might be the problem.